# Multiple Fields for Prefix in ElasticSearch and auto From and Size limit

Tags: json, lucene, elasticsearch, prefix

I got 2 questions related to ElasticSearch.

1) *First Question*, I have this query with prefix

```
"must": [
        {
           "prefix": {
              "user": "John"
           }
        }
     ]
```

with this query, I can ***Prefix***  ***John*** with ***User*** field so it results those documents in which John is found in User field. Now how can I make this query to see if John is prefixed in either any of ***User or email fields***.

---

2) *Second Question*, I know we can apply *Size* and *from* in ElasticSearch to limit Result but I want to know that do I have to explicitly provide  *Size* and *from* every time I query in ElasticSearch to continue last result or is there any other way to let the ElasticSearch do it for me that I just query and it will give results in a series left from previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that the `prefix`-query does not do any text analysis, so you will not be matching e.g. `john` with your query.

You should look into the [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)-query which takes the options of the [match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)-query as well. Thus, you can combine `multi_match` with `phrase_prefix` and get the best of both: matching on multiple fields, and text analysis.

Here is a runnable example you can play with: https://www.found.no/play/gist/8197442

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"user":"John Smith","email":"john.smith@gmail.com"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"user":"Alice Smith","email":"john.smith@gmail.com"}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
                "user",
                "email"
            ],
            "query": "john",
            "operator": "and",
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
        }
    }
}
'
```

For your second question, look into the [scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) API.

Comment: Great Job @Alex Brasetvik. Thanks Alot man. It just worked like charm. But Scroll document is stating which confuses me that "_Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, it is intended for cases like scrolling over large portions of data that exists within elasticsearch to reindex it for example_: what that means. I am thinking that my users would be making thousands of searches from different machines. How can I implement it then?

Comment: I might have misread your second question. You should probably stick with using `size` and `from`. It's simple and probably plenty fast. You'll have to translate what page your user is on to the appropriate `from`-parameter.

Comment: Ok Alex I got it. Thanks alot for your kind help.